# regex that extracts $ and % values from the string

Tags: python, regex

Lets say the string

`str1 = "4.1%  Cash Back "`

`str2 = "$44.2  miles "`

I want to extract both "4.1%" and "$44.2" from the string. what is the best solution. I tried several methods but didn't go well.

I  tried following regex:

```
  pattern1 = r'(\d+\.\d+*%)'
  pattern2 =  r'$(\d+\.\d+*)'
```

Comment: You probably need to escape the `$` and `%` symbols, e.g. `r'(\$\d+\.\d+*)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape `$` with `\`:

```
pattern = r'\d+(\.\d+)?%|\$\d+(\.\d+)?'
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI2tK7/3)

Comment: @Fabricator How about if there is no decimal numbers.??
It doesn't accept numbers with no decimal

Comment: @sudobomb, make `(\.\d+)` optional by adding `?`

Comment: `pattern = r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?%|\$\d+\.\d+'` - same as above, but with the decimal part marked as optional.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> str1 = "4.1%  Cash Back "
>>> str1.split()[0]
'4.1%'
>>> str2 = "$44.2  miles "
>>> str2.split()[0]
'$44.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to escape the '.' sign
and You should escape $ sign.
Use Patterns as:

```
pattern1 = r'\d+.\d+%'
pattern2 = r'\$\d+.\d+'
```